# Is there a way to cast the type of a variable that is returned from a svelte component?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I currently have a svelte component which supports searches to Typesense and returns the results back to the parent so they can be displayed differently, based on whatever is passed into the slot.

I used unions to hint the return type of the result and I end up getting the error

```
Property 'price' does not exist on type 'Fruit | Fluid'.
Property 'price' does not exist on type 'Fluid'.ts(2339)

Property 'viscosity' does not exist on type 'Fruit | Fluid'.
Property 'viscosity' does not exist on type 'Fruit'.ts(2339)

Property 'price' does not exist on type 'Highlight<Fruit | Fluid>'.
Property 'price' does not exist on type 'Highlight<Fluid>'.ts(2339)

Property 'viscosity' does not exist on type 'Highlight<Fruit | Fluid>'.
Property 'viscosity' does not exist on type 'Highlight<Fruit>'.ts(2339)
```

Is there any way to cast the type of the result variable returned or pass a type into the component so it will only return either type `ExampleResponse<Fruit>` and `ExampleResponse<Fluid>`? It's not limited to just `Fruit` and `Fluid`, they're just dummy classes for this post.

There aren't any runtime errors, just with typing.
Below is an example program of how it's done:

```html
<!-- main +page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import Search from './Search.svelte';
</script>

<Search searchParams="fruit" let:result>
    <div>
        <div>Fruit is {result.document.name}</div>
        <div>Price is {result.document.price}</div>
        <div>Highlighted price is {result.highlight.price.snippet}</div>
    </div>
</Search>

<Search searchParams="fluid" let:result>
    <div>
        <div>Fluid is {result.document.name}</div>
        <div>Viscosity is {result.document.viscosity}</div>
        <div>Highlighted viscosity is {result.highlight.viscosity.snippet}</div>
    </div>
</Search>
```

```html
<!-- Search.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    export let searchParams: 'fruit' | 'fluid';
    let results: ExampleResponse<Fruit | Fluid>[] = [];

    onMount(() => search);

    async function search() {
        // populate results with fruit or fluid
        // based on searchParams
    }
</script>

{#each results as result}
    <slot {result} />
{/each}
```

```js
// ambient.d.ts
type Fruit = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    color: string;
    price: number;
};

type Fluid = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    color: string;
    viscosity: number;
};

type Highlight<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: HighlightInfo;
};

type HighlightInfo = {
    marked: string;
    snippet: string;
};

type ExampleResponse<T> = {
    document: T;
    highlight: Highlight<T>;
};
```

I have tried forcing the types using `in` within an if block which works but feels more like a workaround than a proper solution.

```html
<Search searchParams="fruit" let:result>
    {#if 'price' in result.document && 'price' in result.highlight}
        <div>
            <div>Fruit is {result.document.name}</div>
            <div>Price is {result.document.price}</div>
            <div>Highlighted price is {result.highlight.price.snippet}</div>
        </div>
    {/if}
</Search>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how TypeScript works, you explicitly are saying that the type may be one or the other at runtime, so you will have to check by what is the correct one.

You can instead check if the type is correct using `if (x.document instanceof Fruit)`, thus getting correct type checking in each branch of the if-else. if they have properties that overlap, you can access them with no typing issue of course.